# vagrant is using the wrong version of ruby

Tags: ruby, vagrant, chef-infra

I'm trying to get 'cloudwatchtographite' gem up and running via chef; but (isn't there always?) it fails because vagrant keeps using vagrant_ruby which is at version 1.8 where as I need at minimum version 1.9.2 (specifically, nokogiri, a dependency requires 1.9.2) how do I install the correct version?

I've tried using

```
 execute "gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3" 

 execute "\\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby=2.0"

 execute "rvm use 2.0 --default"
```

but it errors with `rvm is not a command" and ruby 2.0 isn't even installed.

I've added the vagrant 'omnibus' plugin and set it to (within the VagrantFile):

```
config.omnibus.chef_version = :latest
```

but it still uses the vagrant ruby of 1.8.

I'm at a loss, how do I get this working?

Comment: I don't get your question, vagrant ruby has nothing to do with the chef ruby installed in the target VM. You may use chef to install ruby on a target and then install gems, but you're not showing anything about your gem install here which sounds to be your original problem (and using multiples `execute` commands won't achieve what you wish as each `execute` will have it's own context)

Comment: rvm usually sets up a script to run on startup (for example in .bashrc).  perhaps you need to manually kick this off before your rvm use command - something like  `execute "source $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm && rvm use 2.0 --default"`

Comment: Are you trying to install the `cloudwatchtographite` gem as a system gem or do you just want to make use of it in Chef?

Comment: managed to solve the problem by just installing `ruby1.9.3-dev` via apt-get. Not what I want but for vagrant it's fine.

Comment: @user3536548 that's definitely one approach, if what you want is to have `cloudwatchtographite` installed as a system gem. If you're only going to use it from Chef, you should use the `chef_gem` resource to install the gem. When using `chef_gem` it'll use Chef's embedded Ruby (2.1.x).

Comment: huh, That might also be a way to go, but how would I use it after it's installed? As `cloudwatchtographite` wouldn't work as it wouldn't be on the path, right?